# Stylesheet depends on hostname

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra

*Sorry my English*

I'm working on multi face site, that runs on Sintra. I need to change CSS stylesheet in depend of given URL.
Like:

```
get '/*' do
    case request.host
    when 'site1.com'
        @style = 'style1'
    when 'site2.com'
        @style = 'style2'
    end
    erb :index
end
```

Then in index.erb view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="../<%= @style %>.css">
```

But if place code like this in action file, all pages content is "style1" or "style2". To prevent this I need to place *case* code in every *get-do* action. I think this is not the Ruby way. Is there exists any possible way to place that "stylesheet rewrite" in single action or another way to implement css rewriting in this case?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First try to call stylesheet files from layout file instead of calling it from view files. Then move that case block to a helper method and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good reason for using a helper method. First add the helper:

```
helpers do
  def include_css(host)
    case host
    when 'site1.com'
      'style1'
    when 'site2.com'
      'style2'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your index.erb:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="../<%= include_css(request.host) %>.css">
```

Disclaimer: I don't use ERB so it might not work out-of-the-box. Also, I don't know whether index.erb is a template common to all your pages, so maybe you'll have to put that line in each .erb file you serve.

Answer (score 0):

better call stylesheet by layouts it will b the easy way